Please find the next number in this sequence: 121, 25, 36, 49, 16, 9,?
Here is the sequence:
121, 25, 36, 49, 16, 9, ?

What should be written instead of the question mark?
Note: Angles in a clock (seconds aren't considered)

The answer is 64.
Because...

 Starting from 12 o'clock on an analog clock, the first time we have an angle of exactly a square number between the minute and hour hands is 12:22:00 (or 00:22:00) and the angle is 121°. The next time we have an angle of square number is 01:10:00 (or 13:10:00) and the angle is 25°. Then 01:12:00 (13:12:00) -> 36°. And 02:02:00 (14:02:00) -> 49°. Then 02:08:00 (14:08:00) -> 16°. And 03:18:00 (15:18:00) -> 9°. Finally, 03:28:00 (15:28:00) -> 64°.


It's fine to leave questions open on this site until somebody gives an answer. One day is very soon to be self-answering - give people time to see and think about the question and get that necessary flash of inspiration! Some questions here don't get answered for days, weeks, months or even years - there's no shame in a question that hasn't been answered yet :)

Between 12:00 and 12:22, the angle between the hour hand and the minute hand increases steadily from 0 degrees to 121 degrees.  In this time interval, there is a point in time when that angle is 1 degree then 4 degrees then 9 degrees …

@Will.Octagon.Gibson Fixed the note

@Will.Octagon.Gibson The solution doesn't explicitly state this, but It appears that only times at whole minutes are considered.  After 12:00, the other square angles (1, 4, 9, ..., 100) all occur at times where the seconds are not at :00.
